# c# .Net Visual Studio show execution path that lead to page display

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have inherited a mostly c# MVC application that has been around for years and is quite the collection of mySQL, stored procs, Web Forms, MVC, WebAPI, JS, jQuery, Angular, and I think there is some React in there as well. I am looking for a tool where I can start the application, get to a particular page, then look at what classes and methods were called to get there.

I know the application needs refactored and, frankly, completely rewritten, and that is happening. We just also need to support this tool as another team develops the next version.

Thanks,
Sammer

Comment: Pages are displayd when the user/browser asks for them, not by other classes. If you want to see the requests/redirects that led to this, use Fiddler or the Networking tab of your browsers developer tools to see what requests were made

Comment: If you want to see which calls were involved in that page, you can use [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/)

Comment: Panagiotis - For MiniProfiler - Unfortunately this application targets .NetFramework 4.5.1 and the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Comment: 4.5.1 is no longer supported and probably not used by your project or servers either - 4.x versions are binary replacements which means Windows Update probably already updated it to a later version. The TLS1.0 deprecation alone probably forced people to upgrade already. You could at least clone the project, change the target framework and try MiniProfiler

Comment: There are other more extensive options too. You could add [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net) to your project and collect analytics (again, the unsupported framework can be a problem). Worst case, you can inspect IIS's log to see the path the users followed from one page to another.

Comment: Panagiotis - Thank you for all the direction. I actually got what I needed from the Network tab in Chromes Inspect capability.

Answer (score -1):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to quickly find C# classes and methods responsible to display a particular page.